# Qbs: Module with submodules

Tags: qbs

To use Qt submodules, you can write something like:

```
Depends { name: "Qt"; submodules: ["core", "gui"] }
```

But is it possible to implement custom module-with-submodules project structure? Like:

```
Depends { name: "MyModule.MySubmodule" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You simply need to nest your .qbs module file one level deeper in the directory hierarchy. Examine the on-disk structure of the Qt modules for an example.

Comment: Unable to find Qt module anywhere in folder `share/qtcreator/qbs/share/qbs` under QtCreator's folder on neither macOS nor Ubuntu.